# alfresco share duplication of document releated issue in alfresco repository

Tags: alfresco

In alfresco share how we can avoid duplication of file when one file share between two different folder.
For example suppose that one file say abc.txt is shared by two folders say folder A and Folder B.Now when i checked out one file from Folder A for editing than how can I lock the same  file so that one could never be checkout that file from folder B.

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make it clearer. Perhaps an example would help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that abc.txt is literally the same object but is linked to multiple folders (which is possible in the Alfresco repository) then checking out abc.txt in either folder will lock it in the other folder because it is the same object.

If you are saying that folder A/abc.txt and folder B/abc.txt are two different objects but they have the same name, then you've got a lot of work to do. You would essentially write a customization that would:

- Replace the out-of-the-box checkout UI action in Share with your own. Your new action would query a custom service (see next step) on the repository with the file it is about to check out. The repository would then respond with whether it is okay or not.
- The custom service on the repository to implement the above logic would have to know how to find matching files. Matching on file name is probably a bad idea. A better idea would be to follow an association. The downside is that this would require your users to link files together with the association.

Of course this raises all kinds of issues such as, what happens when someone checks out the linked file (sitting in Folder B) in between the time your service checked and said no one had the linked file checked out and the time the UI action decides to invoke the checkout on the file sitting in Folder A.